# laravel hotrush/Webshotter always show page load timeout

Tags: laravel

I use this method to convert html to png, and it always throw error "page load timeout", i don't known where it is wrong, please help me, thanks very much!

```
$jpg = $webshot
            ->setUrl('https://baidu.com/')
            ->setWidth(1200)
            ->setHeight(800)
            ->setTimeout(45) // set timeout in seconds, 30 seconds default
            ->setFullPage(false) // set to true to get full page screenshot (width/height will be used for viewport only)
            ->waitForImages() // wait when all images will load
            ->setImagesLoadingTimeout(180) // images loading timeout, will failt if not loaded
            ->saveToPng('baidu_full', 'myimages/');
```

Comment: What if you remove the trailing `/` from the URL. Does that work?

Comment: I test it, it still throw that error.  @Douwe de Haan